# SVG Chess Fonts are not Solid

Tags: svg, fonts, transparent, chess

I convert PGN chess pieces into SVG files then load them up into Glyphr Studio that makes a .OTF file so that I use then in various chess programs.

Unfortunately after installing the font the white pieces are all transparent instead of being a solid white piece.

Could someone have a look at my code to see why I have this problem, this is the white rook.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 20010904//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd">
<svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 width="315.000000pt" height="271.000000pt" viewBox="0 0 315.000000 271.000000"
 preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">

<g transform="translate(0.000000,271.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)"
fill="#000000" stroke="none">
<path d="M387 2423 c-4 -3 -7 -386 -7 -850 l0 -843 -57 -26 c-67 -29 -126 -82
-155 -138 -29 -57 -36 -173 -13 -233 24 -63 94 -135 158 -164 l52 -24 1205 0
c1161 0 1207 1 1254 19 200 77 252 338 95 481 -24 23 -70 51 -101 64 l-58 23
-2 847 -3 846 -305 0 -305 0 -3 -162 -2 -163 -130 0 -130 0 -2 163 -3 162
-305 0 -305 0 -3 -162 -2 -163 -130 0 -130 0 -2 163 -3 162 -301 3 c-165 1
-303 -1 -307 -5z m473 -298 l0 -165 270 0 270 0 0 165 0 165 170 0 170 0 0
-165 0 -165 270 0 270 0 0 165 0 165 170 0 170 0 0 -780 0 -780 -1050 0 -1050
0 0 780 0 780 170 0 170 0 0 -165z m1912 -1562 c118 -54 118 -202 0 -256 l-47
-22 -1150 0 -1150 0 -47 22 c-57 26 -88 71 -88 128 0 46 28 98 62 116 70 38
70 38 1238 36 l1135 -2 47 -22z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Sorry I was getting a error message everytime I tried ti paste the code in

Comment: I am still getting this error but it doesn't matter as it is all too complicated even just trying to post here but thanks Robert for taking an interest in my post. Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Managed to do it

Comment: how about adding a white rect as the first element in the SVG to give the piece a white background?